# How to pass array variables based on condition to PHP using post method

Tags: javascript, php, post, dom-events

I have an array:

```
$k[23]='something'; 
$k[44]='something more';
```

If a user enters 2,3 and presses 'go' in a virtual 10 digit keypad (will look like a calculator), I need to pass 'something' to browse.php.

If the user press 4,4 and press go, then I have to pass 'something more' to browse.php.

Any ideas? I am new to Javascript/PHP.

Comment: So where is this array? Client or server side?

Comment: array is with in the page.. so client..

Comment: Do you have $k[2] and $k[3] too? or is that $k["02"] for example

Comment: yes array have so many , say $k[0] to $k[100]

Comment: What are you really asking here? Are you asking about how to store it? Are you asking how to create an HTML form? Do you want to do this as AJAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or this:

```
<script>
var $k=[];
$k[23]="something"; 
$k[44]="something more";
function pass(theForm) {
  var val = parseInt(theForm.lcd.value);
  if ($k[val]) window.frames["f1"].location='http://google.com/search?q='+escape($k[val]);
  return false
} 
</script>
<form onsubmit="return pass(this)">
<input type="text" name="lcd" value="" />
<input type="button" value="2" onClick="this.form.lcd.value+=this.value" />
<input type="button" value="4" onClick="this.form.lcd.value+=this.value" />
<input type="submit" value="GO" >
</form>
<iframe name="f1" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store as a string and reference as $k[$textEntered];

So $textEntered could equal 23 which will point to 'something';

Comment: how to store the data getting from button flicks from an html form